# Why is my dmesg log full of apparmor messages about snapd-confine

Tags: snap, apparmor

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

I've been ignoring this for months because it's just an annoyance, but does anyone know of an easy way to stop these messages from flooding my `dmesg`?

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1592907153.756:165): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/snap/core/9289/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0" pid=19919 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1849753/comments/4):

"A workaround could be to avoid snap run and call node from /snap/node/current/... instead of through /snap/bin/node."

But to directly answer your question:
"This is a limitation in apparmor itself, where we cannot say that snap-confine can inherit and pass a file descriptor to another process, whatever that file may be." ([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1849753/comments/2))

You will find further explanations in the bug report. Discussions are ongoing.